# Moving files between directories automatically

Tags: files, cron

I know what I am trying to achieve can be done via cron job, but I know nothing about coding this at all.

I have a directory on a website that it updated with new files from an external source daily. After these files have been deposited in this directory, I want a cron job to take them and move them to an archive in another folder under the same domain (not in the same directory).

How can I achieve this?

Further details: the server is running Linux Redhat and I operate it via cPanel. The archive isn't actually an archive but just another directory where the files will live until I decide to delete them. The files themselves are .zip and csv files. There are a total of 2 files that originate on the server on a daily basis which need to be moved across by the end of the day.

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty broad as it is. Please edit the question to add some details about your server's environment (e.g., what OS is it, is there a control panel, what scripting languages do you have installed, etc...), an example of the files and the path on your server that you want to backup to, and what type of archive (e.g., zip, tar, etc...) you want to save it to.

Comment: It's a Linux Redhat OS. I used cPanel as its a shared hosting account so all the standard scripts that come with shared hosting I will most likely have. 

Lets say the path is: domain.com/data 

I want to get the files from the /data/ directory and move them to domain.com/data archive

'Archive' not to mean that it needs to be a .zip file, but simply to denote it's a storage directory for the older dated files from the /data directory.